# possessive determiner my , mine is what?

Tags: pronouns, possessives, determiners

*My* and *mine* are both called *possessive pronouns*

*My* is called a *possessive determiner*

What is *mine* also called?

Comment: Where does it say that they are both "possessive pronouns"? It looks like just one, _mine_, is a possessive pronoun.

Comment: @Max see [**Cambridge Dictionary**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/pronouns-possessive-my-mine-your-yours-etc), e.f.

Comment: @P.E.Dant Thanks. I cited that in my answer earlier. It does not say that the two are possessive pronouns. So I'm wondering where OP read this. It could be a matter of conflicting theory/terminology, though unlikely.

Comment: OED says that _mine_ is _possessive adjective and pronoun of the first person singular._ I don't have a higher authority than that at my disposal, @learner !

Comment: @Max Look closely at the Cambridge entry. The bold header seems to say that _all_ of them are possessive pronouns: **Pronouns: possessive (my, mine, your, yours, etc.)**

Comment: @P.E.Dant I see your point. The entry does suggest that the two are separate, and the table calls one a possessive determiner and the other a possessive pronoun. But I just saw a link that calls the two possessive pronouns, and I wouldn't be surprised if there is a special name other than possessive pronoun for mine.

Comment: @Max There is such a label: _possessive adjective,_ per the OED.

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be some conflicting theory on the matter. According to Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possessive_determiner), "For example, under this scheme, _my_ is termed a dependent possessive pronoun and _mine_ an independent possessive pronoun."

Comment: Since I or anyone can, at any time, edit the Wikipedia article to state authoritatively that _mine_ is a _remotely-determined third order fremilac,_ I'll take the OED. That's just me, though.

Answer (score 1):

**Ron Cowan The Teacher's Grammar of English**(Cambridge) calls them *possessive determiners* and *possessive pronouns*(Chapter 13). Sorry, I have a paper book.

From Grammar.about.com

Possessive determiners are sometimes called possessive adjectives, weak possessive pronouns, genitive pronouns, possessive determiner pronouns, or simply possessives.